# What are 'hydrophilic' spheres?

Tags: material-science, fluid-statics, surface-tension

So, I know that a hydrophilic material is defined as those with a special affinity for water, opposite to hydrophobic, those that naturally repel water.

I am investigating the impact of spheres with water surfaces, and the splashes caused by them. However, one research paper focuses on the difference between the fluid dynamics of hydrophilic spheres and hydrophobic spheres, and the difference in the cavities they make when they sink underwater.

I understand what a hydrophobic sphere is, but what is a hydrophilic sphere? Like the water absorbing waterbeads/orbeez that get bigger(the ones children play with)?

I am planning to use orbeez/waterbeads.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 0):

The hydrophilicity or hydrophobicity of a surface is an indication of the contact angle that an air-water interface makes with the surface. On hydrophilic surfaces the water-air interface has a small angle so drops of water on the surface tend to spread out. On hydrophobic surfaces the water-air interface has a high angle so drops of water on the surface tend to roll up.

A *hydrophilic sphere* just means a sphere that has a hydrophilic surface, and likewise a *hydrophobic sphere* is a sphere with a hydrophobic surface. The hydrophilicity of the surface affects the interaction with water because a low contact angle tends to pull the sphere into the water and a high contact angle tends to push the sphere out of the water. It makes sense that this would affect the splash as the sphere hits a water surface, though I have no personal experience of doing this type of experiment.